# SwiftData app crashes only when deployed via TestFlight

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios17, swift-data

This SwiftData issue has me stumped.  My app, when uploaded via cable works fine but when it is deployed via TestFlight it crashes immediately on startup while trying to do the first fetch for data.

Here is a screenshot of the crash report ...
[image]

I've tried the following things to fix the issue:

1. Disabled `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` configuration to `No Optimization` for both **Debug** and **Release**
2. I tried calling the `fetch` from a `task()` modifier instead of `onAppear()`
3. I deleted the app from the device before reinstalling it via TestFlight
4. I tried it on a different device with a different iCloud account.

Here is the code that is calling the `fetch()` inside a ViewModel.

```swift
func refresh(_ ctx: ModelContext) {
    records.removeAll()
    
    let wRecs: [WeightRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: wRecs)
    
    let bpRecs: [BloodPressureRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: bpRecs)
    
    let mdRecs: [MedicationTakenRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: mdRecs)
    
    let bmRecs: [BowelMovementRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: bmRecs)
    
    let seRecs: [SideEffectRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: seRecs)
    
    let fdRecs: [FoodConsumedRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: fdRecs)
    
    let pmpRecs: [PumpChangeRecord] = fetchAll(ctx)
    records.append(contentsOf: pmpRecs)
    
    records.sort { lRec, rRec in
        lRec.recordedOn < rRec.recordedOn
    }
}

func fetchAll<R: PersistentModel & Record>(_ ctx: ModelContext) -> [R] {
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<R>(
        sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.recordedOn)]
    )
    
    return (try? ctx.fetch(fetchDescriptor)) ?? []
}
```

Any ideas what might I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it could help to replace `try?` with  `try` and see if any error is thrown.

Comment: I'll try that but it should just return an empty array if there was an error thrown.  It shouldn't crash.

Comment: I commented out the call to `refresh()` at startup and the app starts without any issues.  In fact SwiftData is used elsewhere in the app without any problems.  Its just the `refresh()` function above that causes issues - but only when deployed via TestFlight.

Comment: Delete the app from the device and delete iCloud manually. Then reinstall it could be a migration issue

Comment: What do you mean "delete iCloud"?  Also I tried this on a device that never had the app installed.  So I don't think its a migration issue. NOTE: deleting the app was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: If this is SwiftUI you shouldn't have a ViewModel object because that is the job of the View struct. Sometimes this kind of crash can happen if you are trying to fetch before the model has been initialised, I.e. a race condition. You might need to ditch the ViewModel and learn `@Query`.

Comment: Settings > User Logo at the top > iCloud > Manage Account Storage > App > Delete Data from iCloud.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/managing_icloud_containers_with_the_cloudkit_database_app/deploying_an_icloud_container_s_schema

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried all things, even crated a new iCloud container, but still get the error. Only on the deployed version. The production version works fine.

Comment: Any updates? I also have this issue